# Run Multiple Scripts after Page Loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following javascripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#HomeSlideShow ul.images').jSlideshow({
            auto: true,
            delay: 15,
            indicators: '#HomeSlideShow ul.indicators'
        });
</script>
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById('Features').style.visibility = 'Visible';
};</script>
```

I would like to combine the first script into the onload function of the second script.  So that both scripts run once the page is loaded.

Comment: Can't you just cut the code from the first one and paste it into the onload function? I'm sorry if I don't realize the problem. Can you explain better what you mean?

Comment: You probably can, my knowledge of java is next to nothing.

Comment: In that case, use Christopher's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will run once the DOM has been loaded. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#HomeSlideShow ul.images').jSlideshow({
            auto: true,
            delay: 15,
            indicators: '#HomeSlideShow ul.indicators'
        });

        document.getElementById('Features').style.visibility = 'Visible';

});
```

or the short hand for .ready()

```
$(function() {

            $('#HomeSlideShow ul.images').jSlideshow({
                auto: true,
                delay: 15,
                indicators: '#HomeSlideShow ul.indicators'
            });

            document.getElementById('Features').style.visibility = 'Visible';

});
```

Comment: If for some reason you want to keep the two bits in separate files, you can just use `$(document).ready(function() {...});` to wrap both of them.  More or less the same thing (if you don't care what order they execute in).

Comment: The second example is just an IIFE, not the `document.ready` shorthand. I assume you actually meant to write `jQuery(function ($) {...});`.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but is their some difference between using .onload and .ready.  After trying .ready it seems to be starting the slideshow before the images have loaded.

Comment: @Reafidy, `document.ready` occurs after the page initialization has reached the end of the document and all the scripts have been executed. `window.onload` occurs after all of the external assets (images, video, flash, etc) have finished loading.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks, so if I understand correctly I DO need the windows.onload event as I want the code to run after the images have loaded.  I cant seem to modify the above for the onload event.

Comment: After forgetting about window.onload and some quick reading of the link you provided I replaced `$(document).ready` with `$(document).load` and it worked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#HomeSlideShow ul.images').jSlideshow({
            auto: true,
            delay: 15,
            indicators: '#HomeSlideShow ul.indicators'
        });

        $('#Features').css({ visibility: 'Visible' });
    });
</script>
```

Use jQuery to add as many things to run on page load as you like.  It could just as easily be done like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#HomeSlideShow ul.images').jSlideshow({
            auto: true,
            delay: 15,
            indicators: '#HomeSlideShow ul.indicators'
        });
    });
</script>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#Features').css({ visibility: 'Visible' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I just don't understand, your code doesnt even have the windows.onload event.  I need the code to run after the page has loaded all the images.

Comment: Okay with a bit of trial and error I replaced, `$` with `window.onload =` and it worked.  I realise everyone will be like 'well duh'.  But coming from a vb.net background I literally know nothing about javascript.  Thanks for your help.